# How to update item_strings in the ListView widget contained in a kivy dynamic class created with Factory, with a list generated in the python file

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

Am currently learning kivy, and am working on a simple ToDo list app just to build my knowledge about kivy but am stuck i need help please. Here is the full python codes and kv codes file link respectively, https://pastebin.com/92eMd776 (python codes), https://pastebin.com/g5cgUJ94 (kv file). My problem is on line 55 of the python file the "list_button" method in the "InputListWidget" class.

```
def list_button(self, list_):
        print list_
        self.remove_widget(self.input_layout_property)#removes the box_layout widget that contains the
        list_view = Factory.ListUnEditedMode() #create an instance of the dynamic class ListUnEditedMode from #Factory
        list_view.item_strings = list_ #then update the item_strings with the list_ values
        self.add_widget(list_view) #To add the list_view  widget
```

Then the kv file.:

```
<ListUnEditedMode@BoxLayout>:
    show_list_property: list_view
    ListView:
        id: list_view
        color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
        item_strings: []
```

When the list button is clicked it clears the "box_layout" that contains the "text_input" field widget, then adds the "ListUneditedMode(Box_layout)" widget that contains the "ListView" widget,  i succeeded in doing that, the instance of the kivy dynamic class - "ListUneditedMode" is created from Factory. The main problem is,  i want the list values contained in the "list_" argument of the "list_button" method to update the "item_strings" variable.. Please any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks (please forgive the unorganized way my codes are written, am just a newbie in kivy, python and programming as a whole)

Answer (score 0):

Did you not write all that pretty code yourself? Right now it just seems to me you want to change line 59 to `ist_view.item_strings = list_`. Otherwise, explain what you want in more detail.

Comment: Thanks...i did, I appreciate ur response, actually your suggestion led me to the actual answer to my question. I replaced line 59 with `list_view.ids.list_view.item_strings = list_` i realized that the "list_view", instance of the Dynamic class, ListUneditedMode is a BoxLayout widget and so does not have an "item_strings" property, so i had to access the id of the "ListView" widget and use it to access the item_strings. Now i want to see a way i can store the title and the list itself in a dictionary, will notify you if i have any problem doing that. Thanks once more.

Comment: No problem, glad I helped.

Comment: Wanted to ask something else. Is it possible to access let's say  `INPUTLISTWIDGET`'s `ListEditMode ` text from `ToDoListRoot `widget and use it in the widget? Thanks.... (Please am gonna b askin sum questions cos like i said am a newbie and this project seems to b beyond me,  which was nt wat i expected but anyway wont give up either, i really apperciate ur help)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask many simple questions. You can reach me at edvardasdlugauskas@gmail.com if you need some more help. Yes, you can do what you're trying to do. You probably need to use the kivy id system. Provide more information though.